# Integer solutions to $x^x=122+231y$

Tags: number-theory

How can I find the integer solutions to the following equation (without a script or trial and error)?

$$x^x=122+231y$$

Comment: If you consider the equation modulo $3$ you see that $x^x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so there are no solutions with $3 \mid x$.

Comment: modulo 3 Yields $x \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $x^x\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ though that doesn't change much

Comment: Observe the equation mod 3, 7 and 11 (prime factors of 231). If all three can be satisfied, the entire thing is solved as well.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Actually, $x^x \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ also rules out $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ as well. Therefore, we must have $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Comment: $89$ is such a solution, based on the fact that $x^x-1=11k$, but, at the same time, $x^x-1$ is divisible through $x-1$, so I let $x=11n+1$.

Comment: I suppose the same strategy could be used for many other equations, like x^x = 2013 + 4157y (just a random example).

Comment: There are two families of solutions: $x_1=11n+1$, and $x_2=5m$, for some *m* and *n*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $f_a:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z_p$ defined as $f_a(x)=a^x$ where $a\in\Bbb Z_p^*$ is periodic and its period is a divisor of $p-1$. Then the modular equation $x^x\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ has only to be checked for $x\in\{1,\ldots,6\}$. And
$$1^1\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
$$2^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
$$3^3\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
$$4^4\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
$$5^5\equiv 2\pmod 3$$
$$6^6\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
Therefore, if $x$ is a solution, then $x\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

Now, write $x=5+6k$ and try to find solutions for
$$(5+6k)^{5+6k}\equiv 3\pmod 7$$
but, by LFT, this is equivalent to
$$(5+6k)^{-1}\equiv 3\pmod 7$$
or
$$5+6k\equiv 5\pmod 7$$
so $k$ is a multiple of $7$, that is, $x=5+42j$.

Now we have to deal with the last prime factor of $231$, that is, $11$.
$$(5+42j)^{5+42j}\equiv(5-2j)^{5+2j}\equiv 1\pmod {11}$$
There are some possibilities now:

- $5-2j\equiv1\pmod{11}$ which gives $x=462m+89$.
- $5-2j\equiv -1\pmod{11}$ and $5+2j$ is even. But this is impossible.
- $5-2j\equiv 4,5,9\text{ or }3\pmod{11}$ and $5+2j$ is a multiple of $5$, which gives $x=2310m+5$, $845$, $1895$ or $2105$.
- $5+2j$ is multiple of $10$, which is impossible.

To sum up, the solutions are the positive integers of the form
$$x=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
89+462m\\
5+2310m\\
845+2310m\\
-405+2310m\\
-25+2310m
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $m$ is an integer.

Some solutions for $x$: $5$, $89$, $551$, $845$, $1013$, $1475$, ...

Comment: I have a problem with $x=47+462m$. The resulting $y$ is not an integer, but rather of the form $\frac{a}{11}$, with $11\nmid a$.

Comment: I think that I have found (and fixed) the mistake, it is $89$ instead of $47$

Comment: Yes, now it works.

Comment: 1023 and 1485 don't work on wolframalpha. It gives a fractional result, while 1013 and 1475 work.

Comment: What does LFT mean here?

Comment: Little's Fermat's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, to know the value of $x^x$ modulo $231$ we only need to know it modulo $3,7,11$.

The value of $x^y$ modulo $n$ depends on the values of $x$ modulo $n$ and $y$ modulo $\phi(n)$.
So if $n$ is prime, the value of $x^x$ modulo $n$ depends on $x$ modulo $n(n-1)$.

A computation gives that
$x^x \equiv 122 \pmod 3 \iff x^x \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \iff x \equiv 5 \pmod 6$,
$x^x \equiv 122 \pmod 7 \iff x^x \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \iff x \equiv 5,31 \pmod {42}$
So far we know that we must have $x \equiv 5 \pmod {42}$.
Out of the $28$ solutions modulo $110$ to $x^x \equiv 122 \pmod {11}$, only $9$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $2$, and those are $1,5,15,23,25,45,67,75,89$ modulo $110$.

So modulo $2310$, we have $9$ solutions to $x^x = 122 \pmod {231}$, and they are $x \equiv 5,89,551,845,1013,1475,1895,1937,2105 \pmod {2310}$

Answer (score 0):

We are attempting to solve:

$$ x^x \equiv 122 \  \mod \ 231  $$

Thus we naturally would want to factor 231 which is

$$ 3*7*11 $$

Thus we can break this into a system of 3 modular equations

$$ x^x \equiv 2 \mod \ 3$$
$$ x^x \equiv 3 \mod \ 7$$
$$ x^x \equiv 1 \mod \ 11$$

upon exploring the equation it appears there are solutions of the form respectively for
$$ x \equiv 5 \mod \ 6$$ (appears to solve the mod 3)

$$ x \equiv 5 \mod \ 84 $$ (appears to solve the mod 7)

And:
$$ x \equiv 1 \mod \ 11 $$ (solves the mod 11 but isn't the only case)

Why these in particular? I don't know...
Its worth noting

$$ x \equiv 0 \mod 5 $$ (the other apparent case)

Appears to imply

$$ x \equiv 1 \ or \ -1 \mod 11 $$

Again: it appears now that:

$$ j*84*10^k + 5 $$ is constant for all k > 0 for fixed j

specifically if j = 0 or j = 1 then for all k > 0 this appears to be solution:

sample solutions include:

5,89, 845, 8405, 84005 etc...

Comment: Try out the numbers 5,25,50, 236, etc...

Comment: works for 5 and 89. Am I missing any solutions here?

Comment: each implies:

$$ x \equiv 1 \mod \ 3$$
$$ x \equiv 5 \mod \ 7$$
$$ x \equiv 1,5,10 \mod \ 11$$ This is wrong. Moreover, the congruence mod $3$ is $2$, not $1$.

Comment: Thanks for that! i edited it. Seems i don't fully understand this area but i have found a cluster of solutions